# Cent OS 6.4 can connect to samba share using smb in nautilus but not with smbclient command

Tags: centos, samba, smb

I can't connect to my public shared mapped drive when I execute the following commands:

```
smbclient -L sambaserver -U student 
smbclient -U student //192.168.1.x/public
```

I get following error: `session startup failed: SUCCESS - 0`. I debugged this command: http://pastebin.com/u0dF8MeL, but I can get access via anonomous with following command: `smbclient -L sambaserver -N`. How can I configure a password ONLY on the upload shared map for a student in Windows? He always ask for a password/login if I want to connect to the public map.

I added student to the `smbpasswd` file. This is my `smbconfig` config file on my samba server:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sigh, Netbios name was longer than 15 characters (sambaserver.localdomain was the hostname), changed it to sambaserver